# Get let's encrypt cert using terraform for App service and App Gateway

Tags: azure, terraform, lets-encrypt

I'm running the commands below, using the file below and have the message issue:

```
terraform plan -out main.tfplan && terraform apply main.tfplan
```

The file is main.tf is:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    acme = {
      source  = "vancluever/acme"
      version = "~> 2.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "acme" {
  server_url = "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
}

resource "tls_private_key" "private_key" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
}

resource "acme_registration" "reg" {
  account_key_pem = tls_private_key.private_key.private_key_pem
  email_address   = "myemail@x.com"
}

# As the certificate will be generated in PFX a password is required
resource "random_password" "cert" {
  length  = 24
  special = true
}

resource "acme_certificate" "certificate" {
  account_key_pem           = acme_registration.reg.account_key_pem
  common_name               = "web-app-hosting.com"
  certificate_p12_password  = random_password.cert.result

  dns_challenge {
    provider = "azure"
    config = {
      AZURE_CLIENT_ID       = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET   = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      AZURE_TENANT_ID       = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP  = "myresource"
    }
  }
}
```

The error output I received is the output below:

```
Saved the plan to: main.tfplan

To perform exactly these actions, run the following command to apply:
    terraform apply "main.tfplan"
acme_certificate.certificate: Creating...
╷
│ Error: error creating certificate: error: one or more domains had a problem:
│ [web-app-hosting.com] [web-app-hosting.com] acme: error presenting token: 2 errors occurred:
│       * rpc error: code = Unknown desc = azure: could not find zone for FQDN "_acme-challenge.web-app-hosting.com.": could not find the start of authority for _acme-challenge.web-app-hosting.com.: dial udp: lookup google-public-dns-b.google.com: no such host
│       * error encountered while presenting token for DNS challenge: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = azure: could not find zone for FQDN "_acme-challenge.web-app-hosting.com.": could not find the start of authority for _acme-challenge.web-app-hosting.com.: dial udp: lookup google-public-dns-b.google.com: no such host
│
│   with acme_certificate.certificate,
│   on main.tf line 29, in resource "acme_certificate" "certificate":
│   29: resource "acme_certificate" "certificate" {
```

Do you have any idea to change it since I already created the App gateway and point it for my App service?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the error when tried with the following code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    acme = {
      source  = "vancluever/acme"
      version = "~> 2.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "acme" {
  server_url = "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
}

resource "tls_private_key" "private_key" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
}

resource "acme_registration" "reg" {
  account_key_pem = tls_private_key.private_key.private_key_pem
  email_address   = "myemail@gxxx.com"
}

 As the certificate will be generated in PFX a password is required
resource "random_password" "cert" {
  length  = 24
  special = true
}

resource "acme_certificate" "certificate" {
  account_key_pem           = acme_registration.reg.account_key_pem
  common_name               = "mydomain.com"
  certificate_p12_password  = random_password.cert.result

  dns_challenge {
    provider = "azure"
    config = {
      AZURE_CLIENT_ID       = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET   = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      AZURE_TENANT_ID       = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP  = "myresource"
    }
  }
}
```

error:

```
╷
│ Error: get directory at 'https://acme-staging-v03.api.letsencrypt.org/directory': Get "https://acme-staging-v03.api.letsencrypt.org/directory": dial tcp: lookup acme-staging-v03.api.letsencrypt.org: no such host
│
```

Then I changed the server Url to `https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory`
You can also check by changing acme provider `version` .

```
provider "acme" {
  server_url = "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
}
```

Then the error is resolved.

```
provider "acme" {
  server_url = "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
}

resource "tls_private_key" "private_key" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
}

resource "acme_registration" "reg" {
  account_key_pem = tls_private_key.private_key.private_key_pem
  email_address   = "kavxc@gmail.com"
}

# As the certificate will be generated in PFX a password is required
resource "random_password" "cert" {
  length  = 24
  special = true
}

resource "acme_certificate" "certificate" {
  account_key_pem           = acme_registration.reg.account_key_pem
  common_name               = "mydomain.com"
  certificate_p12_password  = random_password.cert.result

  dns_challenge {
    provider = "azure"
    config = {
      AZURE_CLIENT_ID       = "xxxxxxxxx"
      AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET   = "xxxxxxxxx"
      AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID = "xxxxxxxx"
      AZURE_TENANT_ID       = "xx"
      AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP  = "vxxx"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Also check the domain name which must be unique and valid in order to create certificate and make sure the dnz zone is created prior to it.

Check for the network /firewall issue and try by turning off VPN as they may block the servers. Restart and try again.

Also refer [Automatic certificate management. Azure Application Gateway & Let’s… | by Evgeny Grishchenko | Dev Genius](https://blog.devgenius.io/automatic-certificate-management-b4ff1b95dbf1#:%7E:text=Here%20are%20the%20steps%3A%20Schedule%20an%20automation%20job,is%20a%20part%20of%20an%20Azure%20storage%20account.) to do it through powershell.